# How does a commercial jet descend?

Tags: landing, descent

When landing a modern Jet such as the Boeing 737, what is the primary source for descent? The elevators or gravity(from reduced airspeed) or a combination of both? Is the glide path angle of descent a series of step downs where the Jet levels out in steps as its descending? In computer generated simulations , it appears as though the plane stays level throughout the entire descent and I'm wondering if that's actually what happens and if so how it is controlled?

Comment: It is a combination of drag and gravity. Both conspire to slow an aircraft down, and it can either add thrust to compensate or descend. Typical descent angles are only a few degrees: Watch the horizon ahead of the aircraft, and you will notice when it descends: The horizon line will slightly move up relative to the longitudinal axis of the aircraft.